# C# - ODBC Parameters acting up

Tags: c#, sql, db2, odbc

So, I am trying to change the design of my program in order to prevent SQL injection, seeing how old SQL strings were made by concatenating TextBoxes with a preset string.

I am using the ODBC driver over a DB2 database.

Thing is, it works in some cases, in others it just doesn't.

Let me give you an example:

Old code:

```
App.Comando.CommandText = "SELECT NOMUSU, CodEmp FROM DB.Users WHERE CODUSU = '" + txt_usuario.Text + "' AND PASUSU = '" + txt_password.Password + "'";
```

New code:

```
App.Comando.CommandText =
            "SELECT NOMUSU, CodEmp FROM DB.Users WHERE CODUSU = ? AND PASUSU = ?";
        App.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codusu", txt_usuario.Text);
        App.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txt_password.Password);
```

This one works perfectly.

However, this one, doesn't. Doesn't throw any error, just comes back seemingly empty.

Old code:

```
App.Comando.CommandText = "SELECT CODMAR FROM DB.Marcas AS MARCAS WHERE DESMAR = '" + marca + "'";
```

New code:

```
App.Comando.CommandText = "SELECT CODMAR FROM DB.Marcas AS MARCAS WHERE DESMAR = ?";
App.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", marca);
```

Just in case you need it,

```
string marca = txt_marca.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
```

In this case, the new code doesn't work, the old one did. I've been pulling my hair out, it just makes no sense.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `App.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desmar", marca);`?

Comment: @artm yes, marca is defined beforehand as the trimmed, toupper text of a textbox. Should have mentioned that

Comment: I meant to use `@desmar` instead of `@marca` inside `AddWithValue`

Comment: @artm doesn't really matter, it's just a name for it. ODBC does not accept named params in text queries. Also, if you look at the first one, the password is called pass in the param and PASUSU in the database. It still works. I'll give it a try though, cause with C# you never know. Cheers.

Comment: In the case that doesn't work, the contents of FROM clause is different; old code: DB.Marcas; new code: META3.MARCAS. Is this deliberate?

Comment: @Arie my bad, forgot to change the name when I pasted the code. There's been a rename but I forgot to include it in the pasted code (Mind you, when I tried the code out, it was the old one, the only thing I had changed was the concatenation for a ?). One of them is the live db, the other is a test one ^^. Thank you, though

Answer (score 0):

have your set the type of command?

```
App.Comando.CommandText = "SELECT CODMAR FROM DB.Marcas AS MARCAS WHERE DESMAR = ?";
App.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?marca", marca);
```

Comment: First one doesn't change anything, the second one gives me an ODBC exception, as ODBC does not accept named parameters in text commands, only in stored procedures. Thank you, though.

Comment: i have modified my response.

Comment: That is not a stored procedure. A stored procedure is stored in the database and can be called from code.

Comment: i have modified my response (again ;)  )

Comment: Tried that as well, unfortunately, the first argument of AddWithValue is basically ignored, so whatever text you put in there has no effect whatsoever. Thank you, though.